# Consuming Web Service in Blackberry Plugin for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am having problem consuming a web service written in asp.net/vb.net hosted at http://www.transmodallimited.com. After writting the code i discovered that the app wasn't really hitting the web service. So, in order to be sure, I went testing with the httpconnection demo and discover that even the httpconnection demo is not working. I tried switching the MDS on, tried adding ';deviceside=true' to my link and it still not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **KSOAP2** you can use this link [BlackBerry and Ksoap2 Tutorial](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/155972-blackberry-ksoap2-tutorial.html). Also see this thread on suppots forum [Consuming .NET Web Service With BlackBerry JDE 4.6, Java Wireless Toolkit and KSOAP](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Consuming-NET-Web-Service-With-BlackBerry-JDE-4-6-Java-Wireless/td-p/61288). If you want to use `jsr-172 compliant stub` you can use [Calling a Webservice from Blackberry Java Application](http://blog.bayestech.com/?p=78).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use any sniffer tool like Wireshark in order to trace any HTTP/XML packages, if there isn't any HTTP/XML package, and your MDS is running before you run your application, then the problem could be in your code.